# Would using a mahalanobis transformation be the same as standardize the variable?

Tags: time-series, python, autocorrelation, mahalanobis

I am trying to use mahalanobis transformation on a single variable that is autocorrelating with itself in a time series that goes from week to week over several years. The mahalanobis transformation is defined as this: "If S > 0 then S^(-1) has a unique symmetric positive definite square root S^(-1/2) The Mahalanobis transformation is defined by The Mahalanobis transformation is defined by z = S^(-1/2)(x - mean x) Then S = I, so that this transformation eliminates the correlation between the variables and standardizes the variance of each variable. Currently this is the steps I am doing:

1. calculate the mean data
2. calculate the covariance matrix
3. calculate the inverse square root of the covariance matrix.
4. Then calculate (x - mean x) * inverse square root of the covariance matrix.

My results give me the exactly same as standardizing the variable (I have 600 values if it's important) so the data is not decorrelated. Am I doing something obviously wrong or is it that the mahalanobis transformation just isn't suited for a singular variable?

I am using python for this calculation so if any of you that see this want to see the code to I can put it under:

```
def mahalanobis_transform(data):
    # Calculate the mean of the data
    mean_data = np.mean(data, axis=0)

    # Calculate the covariance matrix
    cov_matrix = np.cov(data, rowvar=False)

    # Calculate the inverse square root of the covariance matrix
    inv_sqrt_cov = 1 / np.sqrt(cov_matrix)

    # Perform the Mahalanobis transformation for a scalar covariance matrix
    transformed_data = (data - mean_data) * inv_sqrt_cov

    return transformed_data
```

All answers appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you mean that you are applying Mahalanobis distance to one variable?

Comment: @Dave Thank you! I am not sure if it is the same thing as I only learned about Mahalanobis, but the book I looked in called multivariate analysis called in specifically Mahalanobis transformation, and in other contexts used Mahalanobis distance so I don't think it's the same thing (?)

Comment: They’re related, even if not quite synonymous. Are you applying it to just one variable at a time?

Comment: Yeah as my problem is that I have 5 variables that contain prices over several years for week to week, and the prices differ quite a bit. The prices are also autocorrelating heavily from week to week with itself and can be seen as a typical time series autocorrelating which is starting high and then going downwards as the lags gets higher. So my idea was to apply mahalanobis transformation to just one variable at a time to remove the autocorrelation from itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you transform just one variable at a time like that, all you’re doing is subtracting the mean and then dividing by the standard deviation. This is the usual standardization procedure and is unrelated to autocorrelation.

To see this, you might consider having your function output the `mean_data`, `cov_matrix`, and `inv_sqrt_cov` to see that they are numbers instead of a vector and two matrices, respectively.

Comment: Thank you and that's what I thought, but my teacher has been really on that we use it for one or another reason. So if you are able to answer it, my datasets contain of 5 regional spot electricity prices and 2 fixed electricity prices. I also have a time variable going week to week from 2010 to the end of 2021. Is there any way to use the data I have available to use the transformation and have the autocorrelation removed? My goal is to be able to compare the regional prices for for example region 1 against the fixed price contracts with uncorrelated data. I appreciate you taking your time

Comment: @hihixd Addressing the specifics of your particular problem warrants it’s own distinct posted question.